# Why does it work to add a parameter to my WCF service operation?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, iis-7

1. I select a new project -> WCF -> WCF Service Application
2. I publish the solution to my webserver
3. I Create a client app and add reference to my web server `http://mywebserver/service1.svc`
4. Client runs the GetData(1) method fine

All is fine - so far.

1. I change the Service Application from: `Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer)`
   to `Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer, value2 As Integer)`
2. I publish the solution again
3. To my surprise, the client app runs the method GetData(1) fine. I would expect it to crash and ask for the second parameter

Any idea why it's not crashing?

I've tried restarting web server service - still doesn't fail.

I've tried this code in Web.config...

```
<caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false"/>
    <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
        </outputCacheProfiles>
    </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Still doesn't fail.

Any idea?

Comment: When you added the reference in Visual Studio, a local copy of the WSDL was brought down, and local .cs files were generated to provide the proxy.  If you update the service and want to see the updates in your client, you need to right-click on the service reference and select Update Reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply because WCF use [Lax Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx).

> In many other scenarios, the service developer can make the assumption
>   that adding a new, optional member to the data contract will not break
>   existing clients. This requires the service developer to investigate
>   whether existing clients are not performing schema validation and that
>   they ignore unknown data members. In these scenarios, it is possible
>   to take advantage of data contract features for adding new members in
>   a **nonbreaking** way. The service developer can make this assumption with
>   confidence if the data contract features for versioning were already
>   used for the first version of the service.

Many Web services platforms, including WCF and XML Web services, do not perform schema validation by default and therefore tolerate extra elements that are not described by the wsdl. It's not the case for every platform and a few java clients perform strict schema validation.

Try to remove a parameter now, you won't have the same results.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx

> Adding new parameters to an operation signature - Client unaffected. New parameters initialized to default values at the service.